# Synchronize received data from serial port with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, serial-port

I am using [serialport](https://github.com/node-serialport/node-serialport) with a ReadLine [parser](https://node-serialport.github.io/utilities/ReadLineParser.html) to communicate between a microcontroller and node Server. In the node side, I am using this code

```
const SerialPort = require('serialport')
const Readline = require('@serialport/parser-readline')
const port = new SerialPort('/dev/tty-usbserial1')
const parser = port.pipe(new Readline({ delimiter: '\r\n' }))
parser.on('data', console.log)
```

In the microcontroller side, I send a counter value every 1 sec.

The expected log is like this:

> 1   2   3   4   5   6

The real log is like this:

> 1   1   1   2   2   2   3   3   3   4   4   4   5   5   5

Is there a way to clear the RX buffer in order to fix the behavior of `parser.on('data',);`?

I tested the received data flow with TeraTerm and I found that values are not duplicated. So there is no problem in the microcontroller side.

Comment: @ahmedkhan Have you got solution ?

Comment: I moved to nodejs. It's better to handle asynchronous events such as UART data flow using Node JS serialport module: https://serialport.io/